# How to prove the following identity involving the generalized hypergeometric function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

Does the following identity hold?

> $$\sum_{k= 0}^\infty\sum_{l=0}^\infty\frac{\alpha^{2k+l}(\lambda+\nu)_{2k+l}}{4^kl!k!(\nu+1)_k(\lambda+\nu+\mu)_{2k+l}} = {}_2F_2\left(\nu+\frac{1}{2},\lambda+\nu;2\nu+1,\mu+\lambda+\nu;2\alpha\right),$$where $\lambda,\mu,\nu>0$, and ${}_2F_2$ is the [generalized hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html), and $(a)_n=a(a+1)\cdots (a+n-1)$ is the [Pochhammer symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html)?
>   I found that this identity needs to hold as an intermediate step while solving an integration, which can be found as the $4$th integral in page $703$ of [the book by Gradshteyn and Ryzhik](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0122947576).

The main problem I face is the double summation in the left hand side of the identity. How should one proceed to convert this into a single summation to derive the hypergeometric function? Any ideas? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well to start, isolate the power terms (2*\alpha)^m .  Now you have Gamma terms as a coefficient on the RHS but a coefficient that is a summation on the LHS.  I would shed the Pochhammers and stick to proving the LHS summation results in the Gamma term on the RHS.  The Pochhammer relations on http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Pochhammer/17/02/01/ look likely to yield Gamma identities that would serve as a start.  The  LHS summation is probably something like a standard Generalized Hypergeometric evaluated at 1.  Just my approach :)  This sort of thing is tedious but if you need I will.

Comment: Thanks @rrogers. I also think this approach might work. I will try it out.

Comment: I had a run at it and took a wrong turn somewhere.  I think about 2/3 of the way through I would need https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General  i.e. $$
\Gamma(z) \; \Gamma\left(z + \frac{1}{2}\right) = 2^{1-2z} \; \sqrt{\pi} \; \Gamma(2z).
$$